# ajax call back JSON object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, asynchronous

I have looked at many many posts about this subject and have tried several of the solutions but i can not seem to get it right.

last attempt

```
function checkzip(x){  

       $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'zipcheck.php',
       data:{zip: x},
       async: false
    }).done(function(r){
        rates(r);
    });
}

function rates(r){
    alert (r);
    if (r !== 'none'){
    m = JSON.parse(r);
    return m;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

json being returned is {"rateA":"125","rateB":"80","rateC":"150","rateD":"130"}

so i want to be able to:

```
new_rate = checkzip('77090');
```

and

```
alert (new_rate.rateA);
```

but I am getting undefined for the returned value

I have tried passing the function in the success: AND .done(), i have tried returning it directly from both instead of passing to a separate function as well while setting async: false.
I have tried placing the ajax call withing a function inside the zipcheck() function and then calling it from within there as well.
I am missing something along the lines of creating an object from ajax or working with asynchronous functions.

Comment: Asynchronous functions don't really work like this. Instead of calling them and waiting for a response, you call them and bind a callback that runs whenever they're finished.

Comment: ok, can you give me a quick example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in thinking your problem is with asynchronicity.  You basically need to do any handling of the response inside the rates() function, rather than having checkzip() return a value.  If you put your alert() call inside the rates() method, you should see some output.

```
function checkzip(x) {  
       $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'zipcheck.php',
       data:{zip: x},
       async: false
    }).done(function (r) {
        rates(r);
    });
}

function rates(r) {
    alert(r);
    if (r !== 'none') {
        var m = JSON.parse(r);
        // Do something with m now.
        alert(m.rateA);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I have done that.. but I need an object i can pass to other functions. so in one function i set the new_rate object using the ajax and then pass it to another function at will.

Comment: That's simply not the way dealing with asynchronous calls works I'm afraid.  If you want to make asynchronous calls, you'll need to work with callback functions as above: It takes a bit of getting used to.